# Can I use a DSL router for LAN to WAN with ethernet?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, dsl

I have an ethernet port that I want to turn into multiple ports, and I want to do this via a separate router. Right now I am using an old "Linksys EtherFast Cable / DSL Router" with my computer plugged into a LAN port and my coax modem from another room plugged in via the WAN port. (I can connect them thru my house, as there are ethernet wall ports near the modem and corresponding ones by the router.) The problem with this router is that I am only getting around 3 mb/s as compared to the 83 mb/s when I plug directly into the wall (via Ethernet). I am looking the TP-LINK TL-R860 [(Amazon Link)](http://www.amzn.com/B003CFATSS), but the fact that it is a DSL router is scaring me, because the router I am using is DSL, and the speeds are horrible. Also, after googling what DSL is, it seems to be a phone line internet service, which is not what I have (I don't think). Will I be able to get fast speeds when I use this router?

Comment: You're confusing ADSL with DSL. ADSL is the form that goes over the phoneline. DSL can be too, but can also be a cable modem. Secondly you are confusing router with modem. A modem connects directly to the internet, a DSL router connects to a separate modem.

Comment: `compared to the 83 mb/s when I plug directly into the wall`  - what internet connection is inside your wall?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal it's just an Ethernet port that is connected to a coax modem

Comment: And the type (model, manufacturer) of the coax modem is?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Its from Verizon. We just got it so it is pretty new.

Comment: Seems to me that you already have a router (that box from Verizon), so you do not need another router, just switch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I know I could use a switch, but aren't there advantages to using a router, or am I just going crazy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40492/discussion-between-jb-war-and-vojtch-dohnal).

Comment: @LPChip - no, DSL and ADSL are the same family of technologies that rely on ATM. Cable modems are NOT DSL, they rely on CMTS. They are completely different protocols.

Comment: @MaQleod then explain to me how I can use my DSL router which has a RJ45 connector for a WAN port with my cable modem?

Comment: @LPChip Because the RJ45 side is Ethernet whether it is built into a cable modem or DSL modem - that part has nothing to do with the incoming protocol. You're misunderstanding how the devices are put together. The modem translates the incoming protocol to Ethernet on the LAN side. The WAN on a cable modem is the cable jack, and on DSL it is an RJ11. The LAN side may include a built in router if it covers layer 3, or may simply be a passive translation. Some have built in switches and offer multiple LAN ports. There may be some out there that have WAN that support multi-protocol input though.

Comment: What model is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an ethernet port that I want to turn into multiple ports

You are probably looking for a switch or a router, but not for a DSL router.
If your Verizon coax modem already works like a router, you do not probably need another router, just buy a [switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FNFSPY).

> Routers connect two or more logical subnets, which do not necessarily
>   map one-to-one to the physical interfaces of the router.

If you do not need to create two separate networks with different network rules (like firewall rules), you do not need more than 1 router at your home. Nowadays most modems come with functionality of router so that you do not need to configure both router and modem as two physical devices.